# How can I add a new external bean to Spring container and autowire all dependencies?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose, I have XML config:

```
<bean id="b" scope="prototype" class="example.component.B"/>
<bean id="c" class="example.component.C"/>
```

And I have a class of the future bean:

```
class Outcast {
    private C c;

    public Outcast(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

I can create a container as follow

```
ApplicationContext xmlCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
```

and I may to autowire my new bean class:

```
xmlCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowire(Outcast.class, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_CONSTRUCTOR, true);
```

But when I run my code I get a `null` bean.

```
Outcast outcast = javaCtx.getBeansOfType(Outcast.class).get(0);
```

Comment: Ofcourse you will. You are only auto wiring the bean you aren't adding it as a bean to the context.

Comment: But I want to add a new bean into the Spring container and connect it with other beans in the container.

Comment: Well that isn't the way to do it as you already experienced. Why would you want to do that, generally that isn't something you want to do? There is an `addSingleton` method which you could use to register the bean as a singleton.